# Passing list of dictionaries as an Ansible extra-vars

Tags: linux, ansible, yaml

I couldn't find any way to pass list of dictionaries to Ansible via extra-vars.

In my case, I am trying to pass:

```yaml
real_servers_list:
  - { real_server_ip: 1.1.1.1, real_server_index: RealServer1 }
  - { real_server_ip: 1.1.1.2, real_server_index: RealServer2 }
```

I have tried the following, as an attempt to start with one dictionary:

```bash
ansible-playbook configure-l4.yaml -e '{"real_servers_list":{"real_server_ip":"1.1.1.1", "real_server_index":"RealServer1"}}'
```

But, I get a failed message:

> The task includes an option with an undefined variable. the error was:'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'real_server_index'

Comment: What Is there in your playbook that is giving you this error?

Comment: I am getting this when I reach the task where these variables are first being used

Comment: Then, share what those tasks are. See [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the documentation, in order to pass complex types, like list or dictionaries to `--extra-vars`, you have to use the JSON string format:

> Use the JSON format if you need to pass non-string values such as Booleans, integers, floats, lists, and so on.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-at-runtime*</sup>

So, you will have to translate your YAML in a JSON format:

```json
{
  "real_servers_list": [
    {
      "real_server_ip": "1.1.1.1",
      "real_server_index": "RealServer1"
    },
    {
      "real_server_ip": "1.1.1.2",
      "real_server_index": "RealServer2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, use this in `--extra-vars`:

```bash
ansible-playbook play.yml --extra-vars '{
  "real_servers_list": [
    {
      "real_server_ip": "1.1.1.1",
      "real_server_index": "RealServer1"
    },
    {
      "real_server_ip": "1.1.1.2",
      "real_server_index": "RealServer2"
    }
  ]
}'
```

Which, on a playbook like:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.real_server_ip }}"
      loop: "{{ real_servers_list }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.real_server_index }}"
```

Will yield:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=RealServer1) => 
  msg: 1.1.1.1
ok: [localhost] => (item=RealServer2) => 
  msg: 1.1.1.2
```

---

Extra: you can also use Ansible in order to translate your YAML structure in JSON, for your further uses in `--extra-vars`, for example, with this task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: convert_to_json | to_json
  vars:
    convert_to_json:
      real_servers_list:
        - real_server_ip: 1.1.1.1
          real_server_index: RealServer1
        - real_server_ip: 1.1.1.2
          real_server_index: RealServer2
```

We can get the JSON representation of that YAML.

Answer (score 1):

Put the variable into a file. Quoting from `man ansible-playbook`

> **-e, --extra-vars** set additional variables as key=value or YAML/JSON, if filename prepend with @

For example,

```yaml
shell> cat real_servers_list.yml 
real_servers_list:
  - {real_server_ip: 1.1.1.1, real_server_index: RealServer1}
  - {real_server_ip: 1.1.1.2, real_server_index: RealServer2}
```

Create simple playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: real_servers_list
```

Use the file with extra variable

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e @real_servers_list.yml pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  real_servers_list:
  - real_server_index: RealServer1
    real_server_ip: 1.1.1.1
  - real_server_index: RealServer2
    real_server_ip: 1.1.1.2

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```